# How to call objc_msgSend from C on modern OS X versions

Tags: c, macos, function-pointers, libobjc

I need to make some relatively simple calls to objc_msgSend on OS X from C.  This code use to work `id event_data = objc_msgSend((id) objc_getClass("NSEvent"), sel_registerName("eventWithCGEvent:"), event_ref);`, however, Apple recently changed the function signature to `void objc_msgSend(void);` to address some issues.  The general consensus is that this should be solved with a function pointer, however, I am unable to get this to work without some ominous warnings about "function called through a non-compatible type" and "if this code is reached, the program will abort."  My new function pointer implementation looks like `id event_data = ((id (*)(id, SEL, CGEventRef)) objc_msgSend)((id) objc_getClass("NSEvent"), sel_registerName("eventWithCGEvent:"), event_ref);` but I am concerned about the warnings. The event_ref variable is a function parameter defined as `CGEventRef event_ref`. Does anyone have an idea for making this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
id (*eventWithCGEvent)(Class, SEL, CGEventRef) = (id (*)(Class, SEL, CGEventRef)) objc_msgSend;
```

This defines a function pointer called `eventWithCGEvent` with three parameters: a receiver (since it is a class method, it is of type `Class`), the selector, and a parameter of type `CGEventRef`.

In a little more context it could look something like this:

```
#import "objc/message.h"
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    ...

    id (*eventWithCGEvent)(Class, SEL, CGEventRef) = (id (*)(Class, SEL, CGEventRef)) objc_msgSend;


    CGEventRef event_ref = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)42, true);

    Class NSEventClass = objc_getClass("NSEvent");
    SEL eventWithCGEventSelector = sel_registerName("eventWithCGEvent:");
    id event = eventWithCGEvent(NSEventClass, eventWithCGEventSelector, event_ref);
    CFRelease(event_ref);

    ...
    //do sth with event...
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the awesome example, it appears to work!  Quick follow up, is this the only way to get this working?  Is it just not possible to do in one line due to undefined behavior?  Can it be a macro?

Comment: You mean sth like `#define OBJC_MSGSEND_DEF(name,receiver,sel,arg1)  id (*name)(receiver,sel,arg1) = (id (*)(receiver,sel,arg1)) objc_msgSend;` and then create function pointer `eventWithCGEvent` with `OBJC_MSGSEND_DEF(eventWithCGEvent, Class, SEL, CGEventRef)` and finally call it in one line with `id event = eventWithCGEvent(objc_getClass("NSEvent"), sel_registerName("eventWithCGEvent:"), event_ref);`? That would work. Or do you mean sth different?

Comment: Thanks for the example.  When linking, add `-framework CoreFoundation -framework ApplicationServices`.

Comment: I have my event generator running in a terminal window and I have TextEdit focused.  The event is generated when I press a key on a Saitek Command Pad.  I can see the event being generated in the terminal window, but I'm not receiving a key in TextEdit.  Could you explain please?